# Passing params to prototype functions from base function in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype

I have the following scenario

```
function foo(options){
    this._initOptions(options);
}
foo.prototype._initOptions= function(options){
    console.log('set some options');
}
```

Now on all browsers this works great. But for some reason internet explorer returns

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '_initOptions'

any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: How did you call the constructor?

Comment: var bar = new foo({id:123});

Comment: That's odd. Is that your whole code? What IE version are you using?

Comment: actually this is an example snippet...the actual code is from air-bnb rendr app: https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/blob/master/shared/base/router.js It works on all browsers except any version of IE

Comment: How does `require` work in IE? Is there a problem with the underscore in the property when making the script browser-ready? Please provide the exact code that IE sees.

Comment: require and underscore both work correctly as in require, loads and instance of the underscore library and assigns it to '_' . Putting a breakpoint in IE, underscore is loaded correctly and assigned to _. Underscore can be found at underscorejs.org whilst require at requirejs.org

Comment: [thi picture](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/2339134/1278987/8474039c-2f2b-11e3-9888-376b368e4ac3.png) is a screenshot on what the proprty inspector in IE shows

Comment: But what [conversion](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) are you using?

Comment: I dont' understand. Airbnb's Rendr works in a way that both client and server share the same code base. these files are merged together. Usin requirejs. My understanding is that they are being converted automatically being that all modules are commonjs compatible modules.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your prototype functions like this:

```
function foo (options) {
    this._initOptions(options);
};

foo.prototype._initOptions = function (options) {
    console.log('set some options');
};
```

Comment: actually it is like that. i just wrote it down quickly and didnt notice the mistake

Comment: How do you call your foo() class? You need to create a new instance like new foo(options); and not calling directly foo() without the new keyword.

Comment: var bar = new foo({id:1}); would be the way i'm calling it. yet on IE the prototype functions are not linked to the base foo function